# rearrange Array according to values order of another Array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like below

```
  var arr = ["x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c"];
  var tgtArr = [{val:"a"}, {val:"b"}]; It does not need to be as lengthy as Array `arr`
```

This is what I have tried

```
  var dest = new Array(arr.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for(var k = 0; k < tgtArr.length; k++){
          dest[i] = dest[i] || [];
          if(tgtArr[k].val == arr[i]){
              dest[i] = arr[i];
          }
      }
  }
  console.log(dest);
```

My Expected output is  (for above `tgtArr` value)

```
  [{}, {}, {}, {val:"a"}, {val:"b"}, {}];
```

if `tgtArr` is empty Array

```
  [{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ee33v/4/). Any alternative for this, it seems not a good way to me as I am iterating through the entire array everytime.

Comment: should explain what you are trying to acheive....hard to tell from code thhat isn't doing what you want

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for helping me to improve the question, I've updated the question.

Comment: It looks like your fiddle has nothing inside of the target array. Is that the problem?

Comment: I think you are doing it the other way, maybe if you loop for every tgtArr to find it on arr it will work too, but effectivier

Comment: @ajax333221 yes, i'd loop through tgtArr to find out the index number of each value in arr, then using that result to construct the final array as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as Paul's answer, but with a loop instead of *map*. It collects the keys first based on the *val* property, then creates a new array either with empty objects if the key isn't in tgtArr, or copies a reference to the object from tgtArr if it is:

```
function newArray(arr, tgtArr) {
  var keys = {},
      i = tgtArr.length,
      j = arr.length,
      newArr = [];

  // Get keys
  while (i--) keys[tgtArr[i].val] = tgtArr[i];

  // Make new array
  while (j--) newArr[j] = arr[j] in keys? keys[arr[j]] : {};

  return newArr; 
}
```

It should be efficient as it only traverses each array once.

Answer (score 2):

Short:

```
var result = arr.map(function(x) {
    return tgtArr.some(function(o) { return o.val == x; }) ? {val:x} : {};
});
```

This is more efficient:

```
var set = {};
tgtArr.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    set[obj.val] = true;
});
var result = arr.map(function(x) {
    return x in set ? {val:x} : {};
});
```

Comment: Since it's a (more efficient?) version of my answer I have to give it +1. :-)

Comment: This will create new objects for all members of the output array, whereas my answer will just create references for those that already exist. Not sure which way the OP wants to go, just figured I'd point that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dest = new Array(arr.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      dest[i] = {}
      for(var k = 0; k < tgtArr.length; k++){
          if(tgtArr[k].val == arr[i]){
              dest[i] = tgtArr[k];
          }
      }
  }
  console.log(dest);
```

Comment: `dest[i] = {}` will replace existing ordered values.

Comment: Instead of `var dest = new Array(arr.length);` consider `var dest = [];`. It's also a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I like using `map` rather than loops for this kind of thing ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBm77/1/)):

```
var result = arr.map(function(x) {
    var match = tgtArr.filter(function(y) {
        return y.val == x;
    });
    if (match.length == 1) return match[0];
    else return {};
});
```

This is a possibly inefficient, in that it traverses `tgtArr` for every item in `arr`, so O(n*m).  If needed, you could fix that by pre-processing `tgtArr` and converting it to a hash map ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBm77/2/)).  This way you've got an O(n+m) algorithm (traverse each array once):

```
var tgtMap = {};
tgtArr.forEach(function(x) { tgtMap[x.val] = x; })
var result = arr.map(function(x) {
    var match = tgtMap[x];
    return match || {};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tmp = {};
for (var i = 0; i < tgtArr.length; i++) {
    tmp[tgtArr[i].val] = i;
}

var dest = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj= tmp[arr[i]] === undefined ? {} : tgtArr[tmp[arr[i]]];
    dest.push(obj);     

}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ee33v/6/)</kbd>